# In Dreamweaver CS5, is it possible to detach design preview (to move to second monitor)

Tags: dreamweaver

Is it possible to detach the design preview from the code view, for use on the second monitor?

Comment: I don't think this is a suitable question for StackOverflow, you might get better results from http://superuser.com/ or http://doctype.com/ and I don't think that many of us here are using Dreamweaver anyway.

Comment: I thought it might be; I am certainly doing development work in Dreamweaver. In my opinion it's as much programming related as a, for example, VIM question or a Visual Studio question, or an Xcode question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't like Split view (vertical or horizontal) you can put the code view portion on another monitor by using the Code Inspector (Window -> Code Inspector, or F10 on Windows, I think CMD+F10 on Mac ). The Code Inspector is a floating panel that you can place wherever you want. If you make changes in the Code Inspector you need to refresh the document, (F5 on Win and Mac) so that the updates will migrate over.

Beyond that you'll need to live with it unless you stretch Dreamweaver such that it spans 2 monitors and then use split view and adjust the split point.

Comment: I've tried using Code Inspector several times in the past, but that's precisely what I'm trying to avoid. It simply does not behave identically to the "primary" editor, and in fact I'd rather use Windows Notepad and manually refresh browser than use DW's Code Inspector. Stretching is... "ungood" when used with monitors of different resolutions.  However if noone else offers  a better answer, I'll accept this.

Answer (score 4):

When you working on localhost try this:

- Monitor 1: dw code view
- Monitor 2: Firefox with Auto Reload Add-on (Reload page automatically when selected local files are changed.)

You will have better results...